# Cómo calcular la cifra i-ésima de un número

Tags: python, spyder

A ver si alguien me pudiera ayudar. Necesito calcular la cifra i-ésima de un número. Por ejemplo:

```
cifra_iesima(1011, 1) = 1
```

Si paso el numero a un string, me devuelve este resultado:

```
cifra_iesima(1011, 1) = 0
```

El fallo está en que tengo que leer el numero al revés pero no se cómo hacerlo. Dejo mi código adjunto:

```
def cifra_iesima(n, i):   #n = numero, i = cifra i-ésima
    n_str = str(n)   #n_str = numero en forma string
    if len(n_str) < i:
       return 0
    else:
       posicion_i = n_str[i]
       return int(posicion_i)
```

Comment: Creo que no estás tomando en consideración que los arreglos comienzan desde el 0. Por otro lado, si bien la pregunta en un principio señala que requieres calcular (en realidad retornar) el valor de la posición `ì` de un número convertido a string, finalizas especificando que necesitas leerlo al revés. Cuál es el problema exactamente?. En todo caso, mira esta documentación sobre cómo invertir un string en python: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_howto_reverse_string.asp. Puede que te ayude con el segundo caso

Comment: tu código funciona correctamente, quizás no estás considerando que los arrays comienzan en 0, por lo que 1 en realidad obtendría el segundo número

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo general no resuelvo ejercicios de clase, pero en este caso tu código ya está funcionando así que lo usaré de ejemplo para explicarte [***cómo invertir un string o lista con slicing***](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_howto_reverse_string.asp) en python.

En verdad, sirve para invertir listas o cualquier cosa que permita usar índices:

```
def cifra_iesima(n, i):
    n_str = str(n)
    if len(n_str) < i:
        return 0
    else:
        # En python puedes usar los índices de manera negativa, es decir, puedes acceder a las listas por el final
        # Siendo -1 el último dígito. En este caso estoy haciendo un *slice* del string, ignorando los primeros
        # dos parámetros, que sería lo mismo que poner n_str[0:len(n_str):-1], es decir,
        # si lo ignoras empieza desde el principio. Esto es así porque los dos primeros parámetros de un índice en este
        # caso son dónde quieres que empiece y donde quieres que acabe. Si los dejas en blanco simplemente lo recorrerá
        # entero.
        # Como tercer parámetro le paso un -1, eso significa que recorrerá la lista al revés! -> -1, -2, -3...
        # De hecho, si imprimimos el string en este punto lo verás claramente:
        string_invertido = n_str[::-1]
        print("String invertido:", string_invertido)
        posicion_i = string_invertido[i]
        return int(posicion_i)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Debería imprimir un 3
    print(cifra_iesima(654321, 3))
```

He dejado la explicación en comentario, y eliminado los tuyos para dejar solo los relevantes a la respuesta. Cualquier duda, aquí estamos.